# Upload with esptool fails with "espcomm_send_command: can't receive slip payload data"

Tags: uploading, esp8266, osx

Uploading a sketch to an ESP8266 board fails with:

```
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: can't receive slip payload data
warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_BEGIN) failed
```

...or:

```
espcomm cmd: receiving 2 bytes of data
warning: espcomm cmd: no final C0
warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_BEGIN) failed
```

This is on OS X with a PL2303HXD USB-to-Serial cable, using the latest official Prolific signed [OS X El Capitan-compatible drivers](http://prolificusa.com/pl-2303hx-drivers/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/igrr/esptool-ck/issues/9) with [the included esptool](https://github.com/igrr/esptool-ck), and for the Arduino IDE there are quite a few blog posts to be found on this problem. But most are outdated, and are not applicable when using [PlatformIO](http://platformio.org) with some other IDE. So, February 2016:

**Install [esptool.py](https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool)**

- `git clone https://github.com/themadinventor/esptool/` (or download the ZIP file)
- `cd esptool`
- `sudo python setup.py install`

**When using Arduino IDE**

- Open `~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.0.0/platform.txt`.
- Find the line `tools.esptool.upload.pattern` and disable that by prefixing with a hash. Check that your version only mentions `-ca 0x00000`, not `-ca 0x10000` as well (like in most outdated blog posts):

  ```
  # tools.esptool.upload.pattern="{path}/{cmd}" {upload.verbose} -cd {upload.resetmethod} -cb {upload.speed} -cp "{serial.port}" -ca 0x00000 -cf "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin"
  ```
- Add the following, referring to the `esptool.py` you installed above and also using different command line parameters:

  ```
  # Fix for espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
  tools.esptool.upload.pattern="/path/to/new/esptool.py" --port "{serial.port}" --baud {upload.speed} write_flash 0x00000 "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin"
  ```
- Restart the IDE.

(One might be tempted to just change `tools.esptool.path` and `tools.esptool.cmd` instead, but beware that the command line parameters need changing as well.)

**When using PlatformIO**

You will find the same `platform.txt` file somewhere in `~/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif/platform.txt`, but that file is not used for the upload. [Instead](https://github.com/platformio/platformio/issues/426):

- In `platformio.ini` add:

  ```
  # ...or whatever your port is named
  upload_port = /dev/cu.usbserial
  extra_script = /path/to/platformio_extra_script.py
  ```
- Create a new file `/path/to/platformio_extra_script.py`:

  ```
  # Custom settings, as referred to as "extra_script" in platformio.ini
  #
  # See http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf.html#extra-script
  # See https://github.com/platformio/platformio/issues/426

  from SCons.Script import DefaultEnvironment

  env = DefaultEnvironment()

  # Must be full path, or use
  # https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

  env.Replace(
      LOCAL_UPLOADER="/Users/arjan/path/to/new/esptool.py",
      LOCAL_UPLOADERFLAGS=[
          "--port", "$UPLOAD_PORT",
          "--baud", "$UPLOAD_SPEED",
          "write_flash", "0x00000",
      ],
      UPLOADCMD='$LOCAL_UPLOADER $LOCAL_UPLOADERFLAGS $SOURCE'
  )
  ```

Comment: hey, it throws an error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program /mypath/esptool.py error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: To avoid errors when programming boards that don't support QIO (e.g. NodeMCU from Amica), you also need `-fm dio` in the command line. So adjust that `tools.esptool.upload.pattern` line by adding `-fm {build.flash_mode}` right after `write_flash` (and before the 0x00000 address).

Comment: Did not work for me. Can I somehow find out if my controller is broken? Have 5 and all the other 4 work without this tweak.