# CLion + Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide

Please, help me to set up Clion + Arduino.

Clion has an Arduino plugin which I've installed. Here is some instruction on Github but I'm fully noob about `cmake` and other things which are talking about in instruction. I have only used Arduino IDE before for my simple projects. Now in CLion I can create an Arduino projects but autocompletion doesn't work. Actually it works but does it on true C, not for Arduino code.

So if you can please explain like for complete idiot, what I should change to get working Arduino autocompletion.

Comment: What do you mean by Arduino autocompletion?

Comment: [look here](https://habrastorage.org/files/198/07e/6fc/19807e6fc0df47a3a5019a5ea42d46a8.png)

Comment: It can't autocomplete what it doesn't know about. Have you installed all the libraries correctly according to what the plug in requires? (Try to compile the Blink example included with the Arduino IDE, do you get any errors?)

Comment: If u explain how to do, I will do it.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, Jetbrains has a [very detailed blogpost on how to do this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/08/arduino-from-hobby-to-prof-p1/)

Answer (score 25):

Rather than using any plugin, I am using CLion with [PlatformIO](http://platformio.org/), which supports several IDEs. CLion then not only gives you code completion, but also full support for refactoring, Git, and much much more.

From [its documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/integration/ide/clion.html):

> [...] generate project via `platformio init --ide` command:
>
> ```
> platformio init --ide clion --board %TYPE%
>
> # For example, generate project for Arduino UNO
> platformio init --ide clion --board uno
> ```

Then import the project in CLion and you're about done.

Some hints:

- Make sure your code is in the `src` folder, and that the main file has a `.cpp` extension.
- For other files: either rename all `.ino` files to use `.cpp`, or tell CLion to associate the `.ino` extension with C++ files. (Preferences, Editors, File Types.)
- Whenever adding libraries to the `lib` folder (and using `#include` to refer to them), just run the above `init` command again.
- If you're using ESP-boards and changed `platform.txt` for an alternative `esptool`, then note that PlatformIO [needs a different hack](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/20219/upload-with-esptool-fails-with-espcomm-send-command-cant-receive-slip-payload/20220#20220http://).
- Rather than using the CLion Serial Monitor plugin, I simply use a Terminal within CLion to upload and start the monitor as soon as possible:

  ```
  pio run -t upload; pio device monitor -b 115200
  ```
- If you always want to upload and monitor whenever using `pio run`, then add:

  ```
  [env]
  targets = upload, monitor
  upload_protocol = esptool
  upload_speed = 115200
  monitor_speed = 115200
  ```
- Nowadays, [CLion has a PlatformIO plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13922-platformio-for-clion) as well, including a menu Tools, PlatformIO with commands such as Re-init.

Comment: thanks for your informative answer. it helped me quite a bit. just one thing: could you further elaborate on the last bullet point? how do you open custom terminals? does that command work on all platforms or just linux? thanks in advance

Comment: @Neuron, in CLion on a Mac it's menu View, Tool Windows, Terminal. (On a Mac, the built-in bash shell is also called Terminal.) But there's no real difference with using a standalone terminal window, except for having all in one place, and it conveniently defaulting to the project's folder. As for the `pio` command: I only used it on a Mac, and it's exactly the same as `platformio`. (Both are installed when installing PlatformIO.)

Comment: you opened a whole new world to me! thanks ^_^

Comment: Thanks a lot, uploading code works for me! But not serilaports, it says: 
`> pio serialports monitor -b 115200`
`Error: No such command "serialports"`

Comment: Okey, it is `platformio device monitor` now

Comment: But CLion don't see dependencies which I add with `pio lib install --save {lib_name}` Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: @invis, doesn't the 3rd bullet point work for you?

Comment: @Arjan hmm, actually `pio init` with argumets helps. My `lib` directory is empty, thats why I was confused. `pio` adds dependencies to his own directory named `.pio/libdeps`

Answer (score 10):

I know this was asked a long time ago, but maybe it will be useful for someone. I'm a beginner, regarding all this stuff, so if anybody knows a better way to do it, please correct me. here is how I set up CLion for Arduino (on Windows 10):

CLion 2016.1.3 + Arduino 1.6.9 + plugin

1. Download and install the official Arduino IDE (1.6.9).
2. Download and install [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files) to 'C:\MinGW'
3. In MinGW, install: 'mingw32-base' and 'mingw32-gcc-g++'
4. Download and install [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/download/#section=windows-version).
5. Create an 'untitled' project, just to open CLion.
6. In CLion > Settings > Plugins > Browse Repositories > Search for and install: 'Arduino' (tools integration), and 'Serial Monitor' (misc).
7. In CLion > Settings > Search > type 'MinGW'
8. At the environment select 'Use MinGW home', and browse to MinGW folder ('C:\MinGW'). Press apply, and wait until CLion finds the environment.
9. In File > Close project.
10. Open any file manager and go to 'c:\Users\name\ClionProjects\' and delete the 'untitled' project you just created.
11. Open CLion, select 'New Arduino sketch project'
12. In the project directory > 'open cmakelists.txt' and configure lines:

    ```
    6: set board version
    7: set port (you can find out port# from the Arduino IDE)
    8: set the path where you installed your Arduino libraries (Arduino sketch folder)

    set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
    set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM3)
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(c:\\ARDUINO\\libraries)
    ```
13. In the upper right corner in CLion, near the green 'Play' button, select 'Edit Configuration', on the left select 'Application' > 'Upload', and set:

    ```
    -target: 'upload'
    -configuration: 'debug'
    -executable: the project name
    ```

    then press ok.
14. In the project .ino file, write some really simple code (blink).
15. Connect an Arduino Uno via USB, and press the green 'play' button to upload the sketch.
16. To start serial monitor:

    - In CLion main window bottom left, click serial monitor tab (in 'the tool buttons')
    - Click the wrench icon to set up port and baud rate.
    - On the top of the wrench icon, click the blue 'connect' icon.
    - If values did not appear 'correctly', click the white 'switch to hex' icon (on the right of the wrench).
    - Before uploading sketch, disconnect the serial monitor.
17. For CLion to properly find the libraries, make sure to use the same name for the lib folder as for the '.h' file. example: for DallasTemperature.h use folder name DallasTemperature. After #inlcude-ing new libs, right click on 'External libraries folder' and select 'Reload cmake project'.
18. You may want to do further configuration in CLion settings like: theme, colours, text size, etc.
19. Also, you can configure some handy 'live templates', like: `serialprintln`, `digitalwrite`, `pinmode`, `switch`, etc. to enhance your productivity.

Comment: It`s very nice tutorial dude, thx very much but unfortunately I`m using linux (. Instead of mingw what should I install?

Comment: sorry, i don't use linux, have no idea about it.

Comment: @Kvach you will need to install `cmake`, `gcc`, `git`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best way to do it for windows